# SSLSPLIT not working with WSS

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, openssl

Is there a way in SSLsplit through which we can bypass WSS over 443? Slack and a lot of other websites are not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, WebSockets are suppressed deliberately.  This will be addressed eventually by implementing this feature request:

https://github.com/droe/sslsplit/issues/216